# How to change the size of an image that was loaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Working off of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snat7wo4/5/) I can't seem to change the height or width of the image. I plan on using a different image the circle is just for simplicity sake so I can understand what's going on.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = elem.getContext('2d');
    
// Add shadow to canvas
context.shadowOffsetX = 5;
context.shadowOffsetY = 5;
context.shadowBlur = 4;
context.shadowColor = 'rgba(30,30,30, 0.5)';
    
// Load circle image (red)
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
};
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/0Kt6H.png";
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Did you try adding a width and height, as in `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add context.drawImage() in the function

```
context.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I haven't done any coding in a long time obviously, lol.